# The usage of "Is not", "Has not been" and "are not being" in the following sentence

Tags: tense

Which one of these sentences is correct?

There are two new courses which **have not been** started yet.
There are two new courses which **are not** started yet.
There are two new courses which **are not being** started yet.

Comment: I don't want to muddle up the question, but *which have not started yet* is a good alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All sentences seem to be gramatically correct. There may be differences in what they convey and in what circumstances each one would be used. The contest for this question is missing, so it's hard to tell which one is the best.

"Have not been started yet", using persent perfect in passive voice, is useful when you emphasize the present state of things connected to the past (the courses were announced in the past, but not started yet at present), and imply that someone should actively start the courses.

"Are not being started" uses passive voice and present simple. It suggests someone should do some action to start the course, but does not link to anything in the past.

"Are not started yet" uses "started" as an adjective; it does not refer to the past, nor suggest that someone is supposed to do something.